# Can optic neuritis be recovered 100%?

Tags: eye, nerves, multiple-sclerosis

I had inflammation in the optic nerve. There was deficiency in my field of vision. That's because of multiple sclerosis (ms). 
Now,  I'm cured. My field of vision is good. I can see everything but the image that I see is a little bit darker. I find it is hard to read small text and I can't distinguish between a bright white color and a darker white color. I can't describe well because of my English but there are still some remaining issues with my right eye.

1. Will these issues remain for ever? If no, how long will it take to be fully cured?
2. I don't know if I should use my eye or relax it?

   - Should I close my eyes for 10 min per day or something like that to relax it and not to stress it?
   - Or should I close the healthy eye and use the weak eye to activate my brain and the optic nerve?

Comment: I shared my story in this video using some 3D graphics to make it interesting: https://youtu.be/b6N1MPzRq2Q

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason to expect a full recovery within a short period of time. Optic neuritis takes some time to heal - if it does - and usually leads to effects lasting for months or longer. Many studies have found that vision will eventually return to average levels:

- **[Hickman et al. (2002)](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12493277):** ~85% of patients eventually reached levels of 20/25 or better in the affected eye, with improvements beginning to show within several weeks.
- **[The Optic Neuritis Treatment Trial (ONTT)](http://jamanetwork.com/journals/jamaophthalmology/fullarticle/420680)<sup>1</sup>:** 72% of patients eventually reached levels of 20/20 or better in the affected eye; this dropped to 60% in patients with multiple sclerosis. Two thirds reached these levels in both eyes.

Note that these results are for acute demyelinating optic neuritis; I don't know if that was what you had. Additionally, this is data from the primary episode. The ONTT found that 35% of patients suffered a recurrence within 10 years. Further episodes could lead to longer (or incomplete) recoveries.

Again, though, don't expect the symptoms to go away quickly, especially if you have multiple sclerosis. While certain factors can lead to a quicker recovery, especially in children, this is seldom the case. Finally, consult your doctor before doing the exercises you list. They are not necessary for a recovery and will not necessarily help at all.

Other references:

- [Royal National Institute of Blind People](http://www.rnib.org.uk/eye-health-eye-conditions/optic-neuritis)
- [University of Iowa](http://webeye.ophth.uiowa.edu/eyeforum/tutorials/Optic-Neuritis/index.htm)
- [Science Daily article from the American Academy of Ophthalmology](https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2008/06/080602114706.htm)

---

<sup>1 This is a review of the ONTT, not the official final report.</sup>

Comment: My vision is recovered 100%

Comment: @user2824371 Congratulations! Was your recovery recent, of did it disappear quickly?

Comment: First, I took IV steroids (solumedrol) for five days. No improvements occurred during those 5 days. Second, I was on oral steroids for about two weeks. I recovered most of my vision during the first week (Including recovering 100% of my field of vision).

Comment: After recovering 100% of field of vision, I found out that the brightness was still a little bit darker or maybe it's the colors that were still a little bit faint (especially the red). I was not so sure because the symptoms were so subtle. I did a VEP test and there was a delay in the electrical signal that passes through my optic nerve. This means there was still a tiny inflammation in the optic nerve. It took about 6 months to restore the brightness/colors. Now, I see normally. It's like buying a new eye :)

Comment: Till now, I still have two lesions in my brain but it's okay. There are no symptoms. Thank you too much for answering my question and releasing my nervousness. I was upset then. I really appreciate that.

Comment: I'd like to post my tests' results here so that it benefits everyone: https://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/0BwgCajJ9oB7FRnJuOXJycEc3ODg